# Neither PWR nor ACT flashing

Tags: pi-3

My Raspberry Pi was working when I first got it. Now neither PWR nor ACT are flashing! I think my Raspberry is not even getting power. What do you think the solution is?

I tried other power supplies, none of them worked. My Raspberry is not working (flashing).

Comment: Have you got any other power supplies and cables you could try? If so, test them too — if they don't work either, it suggests your Pi may be dead. Let us know what happens with an [edit].

Comment: "It's dead, Jim."

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multimeter, try putting it on the +5v pins and ground, see if you have voltage there.
Or you can try one of those USB meters if you got one, and see the voltage/amps flowing to it.